# Bot not counting the amount of reactions discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a bot like the Mee6 xp system but for specific reactions, I'm stuck on the bot counting the amount of reactions and storing them to display later on. The problem I am facing is that the counter is at 0 no matter what I do.

Edit: Took out the second client.on and now i get the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')"

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, message) => {

    console.log(message)
    console.log('upvote')

    if(reaction.emoji.id === '<:Upvote:577977768944467978> '){
        if(message.author.id == '495622453704261662'){
            arusKarma = (arusKarma+1);
        };
    };

        if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
        if(command === 'ping'){
            message.reply('pong');
        };

        if(command === 'karma'){
            if(message.author.id == '495622453704261662'){
                message.reply('You have '+arusKarma+' karma');
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You should *not* be calling `client.on('message', ...` from within an event handler. This is a surefire way to crash your bot with memory leaks. Instead, register all of your event handlers at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

the event 'messageReactionAdd' returns a MessageReaction & User. It does not return a message event.

Instead do

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    ...
    const message = reaction.message
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: the bot still doesn't read the message, https://imgur.com/a/z6ZYxFE attached 2 images here showing it doesn't react to the message

Comment: if you console.log() the command what does it show.

Comment: After a relook of your screenshot, you aren't reacting to the message with v$karma so the command section will not run

Comment: i get this https://imgur.com/a/CwjSvzg when i log it, and what do you mean by im not reacting to the message

Comment: if you look in the screenshot you sent me the message object has a content variable inside of it with the value 'a'.
Do message.content inside your code to display/access the value.